# register a swift thread as pj_thread

Tags: ios, c, multithreading, pjsip, swift2

I'm currently working on an iOS app using pjSIP and swift.

I got a method on in a .c-file for making a call, let it be

```
void makeCall(const char *destUri){
    ...
    status = pjsua_call_make_call(...
}
```

and I got a swift method that is called from the main thread which is calling the makeCall-function from the C-file.

If I do so, the app crashes and by saying that I need to register the thread to pjSIP before calling anymore pjLib functions.

To register a thread to pjSIP I need to call the function [pj_thread_register](http://www.pjsip.org/pjlib/docs/html/group__PJ__THREAD.htm#ga600d2f8baddfd78de3b6b60cce027a9a)

I tried to add the thread as UnsafeMutablePointer.

my calls look like this right now:

```
void makeCall(const char *destUri, long threadDesc, pj_thread_t **thread){
    ...
    pj_thread_register(NULL, &threadDesc, thread);
    status = pjsua_call_make_call(...
}


internal static func makeSIPCall(numberToCall: String){
    ...
    let destination = ... //my call destination
    let thread : NSThread = NSThread.currentThread()
    let observer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CopaquePointer>(Unmanaged.passUnretained(thread.self).toOpue())

    makeCall(destination, Int(thread.description)! as Clong, observer)

}
```

Thread 1: EXC_Breakpoint and the fatal error "found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

So how can I pass the needed properties of the thread from swift to C?

Comment: This is a terrible bit of design on the part of the authors of pjSIP as it prevents you using GCD - which is the natural thing to do in these circumstances.

Comment: @marko it's not the PJSIP guys fault, it's Apple fault. Swift still has some limitations when used with C.

Comment: Neither of you are wrong, it's just that there are two different issues. Anything that expects/depends on a particular thread is incompatible with GCD, because GCD is an abstraction layer that deliberately insulates you from directly working with threads (generally a wonderful thing). Aside from the main queue, you don't have **any** control over what thread a queue actually runs on at any given time (the main queue is the lone obvious exception). That doesn't have anything to do with Swift, though; it's the same in Obj-C.

Comment: It's nonetheless hard for me to fault PJSIP for this, as it's a cross-platform library and can't really be expected to work nicely with everyone's platform-specific concurrency APIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try not to send an reference from swift but use this directly within your 
.c-file:

```
void makeCall(const char *destUri, long threadDesc, pj_thread_t **thread){
    ...
    pj_thread_desc a_thread_desc;
    pj_thread_t *a_thread;

    if (!pj_thread_is_registered()) {
        pj_thread_register(NULL, a_thread_desc, &a_thread);
    }
    status = pjsua_call_make_call(...
}
```

Source: ipjsua (demo project you get after building pjSIP)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible to write the same function as mentioned in the accepted answer in Swift.

```
func registerThread() {
   if pj_thread_is_registered() == 0 {
     var thread: OpaquePointer?
     var threadDesc = Array(repeating: 0, count: Int(PJ_THREAD_DESC_SIZE))                      
     pj_thread_register(nil, &codecInfos[0], &thread)
   }
}
```

*threadDesc* and *thread*  will be filled after *pj_thread_register* returns.

This behaviour was not obvious to me as no information about the thread is explicitly passed to *pj_thread_register*. Yet I can call this function from any GCD dispatch queue and this conditionally registers the threads used.

Answer (score 0):

you can use escaping to make sure you are always using your registered thread

```swift
let pjsipQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.yourapp.pjsip")

func executePjsipOperation(_ operation: @escaping () -> Void) {
    pjsipQueue.async {
        if pj_thread_is_registered() == 0 {
            var thread: OpaquePointer?
            var threadDesc = Array(repeating: 0, count: Int(PJ_THREAD_DESC_SIZE))
            pj_thread_register("SwiftThread", &threadDesc, &thread)
        }

        operation()
    }
}
```